# XCode 6 won't let me put autolayout constraints on UIView. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

1) I am using XCode 6 and  add a UIViewController to my storyboard.

2) I add an UITableView and another UIView "Footer" to the UIViewController's View.

3) Now I want to set some autolayout constraints on the UITableView  make the Footer always stay at the bottom of the TableView  (but above the bottom Toolbar)

4) I hit the  XCode "Align" Icon to set some constraints.

Unfortunately all interesting constraints like "Bottom Edges" etc are disabled.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually some constraints can be only set by right-click-drag.

On the view from which you want to add `constraint`, you press and hold the right mouse button.
Then drag and drop to view on which you need to bound this `constraint`.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to firstly select the `tableView` in storyboard to make those options selectable.